# How do I check if the data in the Spinner is selected? In Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, controls, spinner, selected

```
 val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.cephe,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            spinner.adapter = adapter
        }
```

There is a my spinner code.

```
 override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View?, pos: Int, id: Long) {

}

override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

}
```

I think I need to write something between the controls written here to ensure the control?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - your question is quite unclear. What do you mean "ensure the control"? You have posted two functions with no implementation. What have you actually tried to solve your own problem?

Comment: Actually it's a simple question. I have some values in my spinner. For ex. 
 <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
</string-array>
I need to check if these values are selected and check which one is selected. The two empty functions here are excerpts from the spinner section of android's own site. I just didn't understand what these functions do and thought they would be used when checking for this selection. That's why I added it to the question.

Comment: Yes. Thank you!!